# Enforcing relational workflows in TargetProcess

Tags: project-management, redmine, youtrack, targetprocess

I'm currently evaluating a few different issue management tools, and have it narrowed down to TargetProcess, Redmine and Youtrack. For what I need TargetProcess seems to do everything with a lot less need for customisation, however as the only person working on QA at a small startup, I'm trying to make sure that as much of the process is automated as possible.

YouTrack has a [workflow editor](http://blog.jetbrains.com/youtrack/2012/02/spicing-up-youtrack-with-workflows/) which allows you to write validation rules for your issues, and would therefore allow me to specify that you can't move an issue of a certain type into a certain state without having a related issue of another type, for example you cannot move a feature out of "New" without having a set of related requirements in the form of test cases.

While this isn't as ingrained in Redmine, there is a [plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/custom-workflows) which allows you to write these types of rules. I haven't however been able to find anything of the sort for TargetProcess, and worry that the ability to perform this sort of deep customisation will add an extra time-sink as I have to spend more time on this process myself.

Is there any way to achieve this in TargetProcess, be it using a plugin or an external service? I can see that I could hook something up to the REST api, but this would make it difficult to give feedback as to why an issue had not been progressed. TargetProcess is an impressive tool, however it is very expensive, and unless it does everything I want, it is difficult to justify the outlay.

## TL/DR

Is there a mechanism for writing business rules into TargetProcess such that the proper QA process is enforced, so I can concentrate on providing value through QA rather than process management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no customized Business Rules in Targetprocess so far. The only thing that exist is a Mashup that allows some rules customization related to custom fields

https://github.com/TargetProcess/TP3MashupLibrary/tree/master/Custom%20Field%20Constraints

Custom Business Rules are requested by many people and we are going to start development this year.